# Property constructor vs Scope declaration

Tags: c#

I am creating a duplex contract in WCF and am following tutorials for how to build out properly. In declaring my client service Callback interface instance I initially declared the instance property as `private readonly` like so:

```
private readonly IEventServiceCallback Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEventServiceCallback>();
```

But at looking at the MSDN example, the interface reference is defined via getter syntax like so:

```
IEventServiceCallback Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IEventServiceCallback>();
        }
    }
```

I'm just curious if there is really a reason to do one way vs. the other or if it's just personal preference? Any feedback would be appreciated.